# Is this regression or another task?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, neural-networks

In statistical learning, what is the name of the problem where say, if I have a picture of a dog, I want to know what percentage of that picture belongs to a dog, i.e. problem/task A)

A) Input (64x64 pixels) Dog picture ---> Output (Number belonging to the interval [0,1] saying how much of the picture belongs to a dog)

And what would be the name for the problem/task B)

B) Input (64x64 pixels) Cat&dog picture ---> Output (2 different numbers belonging to the intervals [0,1] and [0,1], each of them representing how much of the picture belong to a Cat and to a Dog)

I thought it was named regression, but I think I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by „how much of the picture belongs to a dog„? Number of pixels belonging to a dog divided by total number of pixels? Or you mean the confidence of the classifier, e.g. with 80% certainty the picture depicts a dog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your examples are examples of regression. You get numbers in (pixel intensities) and then get numbers out (a discrete proportion). The second example is actually multivariate regression, since your output is two-dimensional.

Thing is the relationship between pixel values in an image and the proportion of area covered by a dog or a cat is too indirect, so no ones tackles that problem that way. Instead, people do [object detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection) and object segmentation, then calculate the meaningful proportion you mentioned.